# How to serialize functions in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, serialization, akka-persistence

I'm cutting my teeth on akka-persistence and came upon the quintessential problem of object serialization. My objects (shown below) have basic types, and functions. I read [this](http://erikerlandson.github.io/blog/2015/03/31/hygienic-closures-for-scala-function-serialization/), [this](http://www.lyh.me/lambda-serialization.html#.WjIDnVQ-d24) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770353/serialization-of-scala-functions), but none has helped me in making the following serializable.

**Test Util**

```
object SerializationUtil {
  def write(obj: Any): String = {
    val temp = Files.createTempFile(null, null).toFile
    val out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(temp))
    out.writeObject(obj)
    out.close()

    temp.deleteOnExit()
    temp.getAbsolutePath
  }

  def read[T](file: String) = {
    val in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(file)))
    val obj = in.readObject().asInstanceOf[T]
    in.close()
    obj
  }
}
```

**Stats**

```
case class Stats(
                  app: String,
                  unit: ChronoUnit,
                  private var _startupDurations: List[Long]
                ) {
  def startupDurations = _startupDurations.sorted

  def startupDurations_=(durations: List[Long]) = _startupDurations = durations

  @transient lazy val summary: LongSummaryStatistics = {
    _startupDurations.asJava.stream()
      .collect(summarizingLong(identity[Long]))
  }
}
```

`Stats` serializes just fine.

```
"SerializationUtil" should "(de)serialize Stats" in {
  val file = SerializationUtil.write(newStats())
  val state = SerializationUtil.read[Stats](file)

  verifyStats(state)
}
```

But this doesn't: `case class GetStatsForOneRequest(app: String, callback: Stats => Unit)`

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
```

Also tried:

```
trait SerializableRunnable[T] extends scala.Serializable with ((T) => Unit)
```

implementing the callback as an instance of `SerializableRunnable`, but no luck.

Ideas?

**Edit**:

Perhaps I should clarify the actual use case that is running into this issue to provide more context. The function is a callback from Akka HTTP [route](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asarkar/akka/master/k8s-watcher/src/main/scala/org/abhijitsarkar/akka/k8s/watcher/web/Routes.scala) like the following:

```
path("stats") {
  logRequest("/stats") {
    completeWith(instanceOf[List[Stats]]) { callback =>
      requestHandler ! GetStatsRequest(callback)
    }
  }
}
```

The [handler](https://github.com/asarkar/akka/blob/master/k8s-watcher/src/main/scala/org/abhijitsarkar/akka/k8s/watcher/web/RequestHandlerActor.txt) actor persists the request until it gets a response. It may take more than one response to construct the final output.

I did some digging and it appears that the callback implementation is a [CallbackRunnable](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/07d61ecf134dbba143531f5a1bd3c1289c437296/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L54).

Comment: What is implementation of newStats() when you pass GetStatsForOneRequest? It seems to work for GetStatsForOneRequest("app", _ => Unit).

Comment: @igorpcholkin just a `Stats` with dummy values. The problem is the callback function

Comment: What I actually wanted to see was  how you construct GetStatsForOneRequest  (including callback) which you use in SerializationUtil.write call.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you didn't fully understand the linked articles. The problem with function serialization is that anything captured in the closure must also be serializable. What you need is [Spores](http://scalacenter.github.io/spores/spores.html). Everything is explained there, but here is gist:

#### What is a closure?

Lambda functions in Scala can refer to variables in the outer scope without explicitly listing them as parameters. A function that does this is called a *closure* and the outer variables it refers to are *captured*. For example `foo` is captured in closure passed to `map` below:

```
val foo = 42
List(1,2,3).map(_ + foo)
```

#### Why is it a problem for serialization?

Looking at the example above where `foo` is a primitive value, you woudn't think that's a problem. But what happens when there is an enclosing class?

```
class C {
  val myDBconn = ...
  val foo = 42
  List(1,2,3).map(_ + foo)
}
```

Now (unexpectedly for many programmers) the closure captures the entire `this` of the non-serializable enclosing class, including `myDBconn`, because `foo` refers to the getter method `this.foo`.

#### What's the solution?

The solution is to not capture `this` in the closure. For example creating a local `val` for any value we need to capture makes the function serializable again:

```
class C {
  val myDBconn = ...
  val foo = 42
  {
    val localFoo = foo
    List(1,2,3).map(_ + localFoo)
  }
}
```

Of course, doing this manually is tedious, hence [Spores](http://scalacenter.github.io/spores/spores.html).

Comment: Where in my question, am I capturing `this`?

Comment: Ok I see. `callback` is out of your control so you can't know what it has captured. But if you go to the [definition of `completeWith`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/5932237a86a432d623fafb1e84eeeff56d7485fe/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/MarshallingDirectives.scala#L61-L62) you will see that it captures a `Promise` which is **not** serializable. Apropos, `callback` here is a continuation function that you have to call before you exit the block, not serialize.

Comment: actually, for the block to complete, callback has to be called. My current implementation saves it in a map, and that’s working. But I understand serialization is a different ballgame