# Avoid capturing `this` when serializing functions in Scala

Tags: scala, serialization

When serializing functions in Scala, we should take care not to capture fields that are not serializable.

```
class Foo(s: Set[Int] = Set(1,2,3)) {
  def replicate(): () => Foo = () => new Foo(s)
}

val foo = new Foo()
val fn = foo.replicate()
serialize(fn) // java.io.NotSerializableException: Foo
```

In the above code snippet serializing `msg` will fail because the function captures `this` and `Foo` is not serializable.

To avoid capturing `this` [SIP-21](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/spores.html) proposes spores for Scala.
Unfortunately, spores only exist for Scala 2.11.x (see this [note](http://scalacenter.github.io/spores/getting-started.html)).
Luckily, I found in [this tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806670/how-to-serialize-functions-in-scala) (this is also described in SIP-21) that one can avoid capturing the `this` reference, by manually creating local values as shown in the code snippet below.

```
class Foo(s: Set[Int] = Set(1,2,3)) {
  def replicate(): () => Foo = {
    () => {
        {
          val localS = this.s
          new Foo(localS)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, in Scala 2.13.1 this does not work and still captures `this` (try out the complete code snippet below).
Hence, we cannot serialize the function returned by the `replicate` method.

Now, I found the following workaround, but it's a rather ugly one.

```
class Foo(s: Set[Int] = Set(1,2,3)) {
  def indirection() = replicate(s)
  def replicate(set: Set[Int]): () => Foo = () => new Foo(set)
}

val foo = new Foo()
val msg = foo.indirection()
toStr(msg) // Works :)
```

By adding an extra indirection, we avoid capturing `this` and we can serialize the function without requiring `Foo` to be serializable. However, I don't want to introduce these extra indirections in all the objects I want to serialize this way. How can I avoid this (in Scala 2.13.1) ?

---

The complete code snippet:

```
// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
import java.io._
import java.util.Base64

def serialize(o: Any) = {
  val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  val oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
  oos.writeObject( o );
  oos.close();
  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray())
}

def deserialize(s: String) = {
  val data = Base64.getDecoder().decode( s );
  val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(  data ) );
  val o  = ois.readObject();
  ois.close();
  o
}


//////////// TRY 1
try {
  class Foo(val s: Set[Int] = Set(1,2,3)) {
    def replicate(): () => Foo = () => new Foo(s)
  }

  val foo = new Foo()
  val msg = foo.replicate()
  val str = serialize(msg)
  val reconstructedFoo = deserialize(str).asInstanceOf[() => Foo]()
  println(s"Try 1: success, reconstructedFoo.s = ${reconstructedFoo.s}")
} catch {
  case e: NotSerializableException => println("TRY 1: Not serializable.")
}

//////////// TRY 2
try {
  class Foo(val s: Set[Int] = Set(1,2,3)) {
    def replicate(): () => Foo = {
      () => {
          {
              val localS = this.s
            new Foo(localS)
          }
      }
    }
  }

  val foo = new Foo()
  val msg = foo.replicate()
  val str = serialize(msg)
  val reconstructedFoo = deserialize(str).asInstanceOf[() => Foo]()
  println(s"Try 2: success, reconstructedFoo.s = ${reconstructedFoo.s}")
} catch {
  case e: NotSerializableException => println("TRY 2: Not serializable.")
}

//////////// Solution (ugly)
try {
  class Foo(val s: Set[Int] = Set(1,2,3)) {
    def indirection() = replicate(s)
    def replicate(set: Set[Int]): () => Foo = () => new Foo(set)
  }

  val foo = new Foo()
  val msg = foo.indirection()
  val str = serialize(msg)
  val reconstructedFoo = deserialize(str).asInstanceOf[() => Foo]()
  println(s"Try 3: success, reconstructedFoo.s = ${reconstructedFoo.s}")
} catch {
  case e: NotSerializableException => println("TRY 3: Not serializable.")
}
```

Comment: The best way would be to move the function outside the class to the companion object.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That's actually pretty neat. Only downside is that i must enforce every replicated data type to be `Replicatable` (this is a trait: `trait Replicatable[T] { def replicate(): T }`) . But unfortunately i cannot enforce an object to have a static replicate method (i.e. a replicate method in the companion object). So, every replicated data type will have a `replicate` method that calls the `replicate` method from its companion object. Is there a nicer solution?

Comment: **typeclasses** sounds like a good way to model this.

Comment: I will look into this, but i'm not familiar with typeclasses in Scala. Feel free to post your solution as an answer, i'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Actually, i don't see how moving `replicate` to the companion object will solve the problem. It will still contain a reference to the object. `def replicate(obj: Foo): () => Foo = () => new Foo(obj.s)` so it encloses `obj` and requires `Foo` to be serializable.