# What is the mechanism by which anonymous functions are serializable?

Tags: scala, serialization

I have read various old StackOverflow discussions on this general topic but there is still one part of the puzzle which appears, to me at least, to be missing.

It is simply this: what is the actual mechanism by which the anonymous function is serialized? And, where could we find its source code?

Or is it all just magic?

Other relevant SO articles (the third of these itself points to some useful articles outside StockOverflow):

- [Serialization of Scala Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770353/serialization-of-scala-functions)
- [Why Scala can serialize...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801305/why-scala-can-serialize-function-but-not-partialfunction)
- [How to serialize functions in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806670/how-to-serialize-functions-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question with what, I believe is the correct answer. The reason I'm doing it this way is that it seems to me that this aspect of serialization is never explained and it does appear to work just by magic. I essentially confirmed (to my satisfaction) the answer as part of the research I was doing to ensure that my question above was indeed appropriate.

But the main reason I'm offering my own answer is that I invite knowledgeable users either to agree with it, to correct it, to expand upon it, or to destroy it. Here goes...

It's all magic. No, I'm just kidding. But essentially the mechanism, once Scala has taken the step of representing the anonymous function as a Class, is entirely provided for by Java. In addition, we, the programmer, need to ensure that an anonymous function is as much pure code as possible: no references to any objects that might not be serializable. The secret sauce is to be found in the Java class: [ObjectStreamClass](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.java.html). Which, in turn, is invoked by the Java serialization classes: [ObjectInputStream](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/io/ObjectInputStream-source.html) and [ObjectOutputStream](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/io/ObjectOutputStream-source.html).

Essentially the serialized bytes contain the full pathname of the class, its *serialVersionUID*, and whatever other relevant information is necessary. When deserializing, the system will simply *look up* the class in the appropriate classpath and return a reference to it. This obviously assumes that the deserializing system has the class in its classpath. The mechanism for that is a little beyond the scope of my research but it's clear that in a system like Spark, it should be easy to arrange.

No (additional) compilation/decompilation of byte code is necessary as the classLoader has everything necessary. I'm slightly surprised to find the ObjectStreamClass in java.io rather than in the reflection package, but I suppose there's an argument for it being there, given the tight coupling with *ObjectInputStream* and *ObjectOutputStream*.

One thing to keep in mind is that while we think in terms of serializing/deserializing *objects*, rather than *classes*, what we are dealing with here is an object of type *Class*.

One more thing to note is that in Scala 2.12, anonymous functions are now implemented differently: as Java8 lambdas. This has broken the mechanism described above in a rather serious way. So serious, that Spark is currently having trouble supporting Scala 2.12. The holdup appears to be this issue: [SPARK-14540](https://issues-test.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14540).

Comment: This is broadly correct, yes. I wouldn't describe it as "magic", but that's just a POV :-). Scala generates a class at compile time for each function type that it encounters in your code. At run time, it generates an instance of that class for each function object you create, containing all necessary runtime data as fields. Those objects can be serialized and deserialized by Java's standard mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks, @Rich that was a helpful elaboration.